# How do I determine if xml is well formed in codenameone?

Tags: xml, codenameone

I am building an app that downloads xml document from a server. I find that some of the docs are malformed and create problems. Is there a way to check if an xml document is well formed?

Answer (score 1):

Codename Ones XML parser was originally designed as an SGML parser and as a result doesn't validate. This also improves parsing performance.

It still sends error callbacks which you can intercept by overriding:

```
protected void notifyError(int errorId,String tag, String attribute,String value,String description)
```

Or by implementing the `ParserCallback` interface. They might not be sent for some semantic errors in XML.